# How to make PHP SOAP call with header security?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I'm trying to call the `GetHotels` function using `nusoap` client and with normal `SoapClient` and I have the problem when calling the function, it returns the following error:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a: InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I use this code with `nusoap_client`

```
   $client = new nusoap_client("http://amandaws.absolutent.it/Booking.svc" ,    'wsdl');
   $bodyxml =('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
     xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
     <soapenv:Header>
     <oas:Security>
     <oas:UsernameToken>
     <oas:Username>XXX</oas:Username>
     <oas:Password>XXX</oas:Password>
     </oas:UsernameToken>
     </oas:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <tem:BGH_Request Language="IT">
     <tem:Criteria HotelCode="FID001" IDRegione="" IDProvincia="" IDComune="" IDLocalita="" IDLineaProdotto="" IDZona="" MaxResults="200" />
     </tem:BGH_Request>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>');
    $client->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
    $client->operation = "GetHotels";
    $result = $client->send($client->serializeEnvelope($bodyxml), "http://tempuri.org/IBooking/GetHotels");
    print_r($result);
```

[Function that i need to call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNmFF.png)

when i print `$result`, i get this array message

```
   Array
   (
  [faultcode] => a:InternalServiceFault
[faultstring] => Array
    (
        [!xml:lang] => en-GB
        [!] => Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    )

[detail] => Array
    (
        [ExceptionDetail] => Array
            (
                [HelpLink] => 
                [InnerException] => 
                [Message] => Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                [StackTrace] =>    at    Absolute.Web.Common.UoW.TransactionService.InTrasaction(Action actionbeBeforeCommit)
    at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
    at Castle.Proxies.IBookingProxy.GetHotels(BookingGetHotelsMessageRequest request)
    at SyncInvokeGetHotels(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
                [Type] => System.NullReferenceException
            )

    )

)
```

If someone helps me I will be very nice

Answer (score 4):

Sending whole request xml with body is wrong, you need to create your request xml starting with header, you can read more in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php).

```
// Set your security header namespace
$headerNS = 'http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

//Create vars for username and password
$usernameNode = new SoapVar('your username', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Username', $headerNS);
$passwordNode = new SoapVar('your password', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Password', $headerNS);

// Create Username token node and add vars
$UsernameTokenNode = new SoapVar([$usernameNode, $passwordNode], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'UsernameToken', $headerNS);

// Create security node
$securityNode = new SoapVar([$UsernameTokenNode], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'Security', $headerNS);

// Now create a header with all above data
$header = [new SoapHeader($headerNS, 'Security', $securityNode, false)];

// Soap client options you choose
$options = [];

// Create your SoapClient and add header to client
$client = new SoapClient('Service Wsdl url', $options);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Now you can create your soap call body and make your request. You can read more about creating nodes with attiributes from [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php).

Use `$client->__getLastRequest();` to check your last request to verify.

Comment: Thanks. i already solved the problem actually and there is no problem sending all the xml request with the header, i had bad syntax in the request. Greetings from El Salvador

Comment: Careful, there is a dash (`-`) missing in the domain name of the namespace. The correct namespace is `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd`.

Comment: I checked and the dash was also missing in the question